# Search for pattern in Python

Tags: python

I have a file in which I need for a pattern and I need to extract the values after the pattern and I should append it to a list.

Sample of file I am using:

```
Container:container_12345

asfacaasda:..........
sdaasdasda:............
dasdadaadada.....

jiasjafjsdf.............
sdfsdfsd..................

Container:container_23456

dasdafsadf....
dfsdfsaf.....
fsfsfsdf......
```

I have tried to extract the values present after the pattern "Container:"  (i.e) container_12345

My code:

```
List = []
pattern=re.compile("Container:")
fop=open(filename,"r")
for line in fop:
    for char in line:
        result=pattern.search(char)
        List.append(result.group(1))

print(List)
```

My Output :

```
List.append(result.group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Output what I am expecting:

```
['container_12345','container_23456']  #Present in that list
```

Please explain me what I have done wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, You do not have any groups defined in your regular expression pattern. [And also you are applying the pattern to the single line character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are a useless complication if you are looking for a static string.

```py
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith("Container:"):
        print(line[len("Container:"):].strip())
```

The call to `strip()` trims any whitespace from the beginning or the end; if you omit it, keep in mind that `line` ends with a newline character.

The actual error in your code is that you attempt to extract something even when `search` returns `None`; also, your regex seems slightly wrong, and you needlessly iterate over each character in each line, so the regex will never match.

Comment: Thank you so much ! But I am getting output only if I remove that  +1.  +1 removes the first letter of container  and results in  ontainer_12345.

Comment: Oh sorry; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the expression on the whole content instead of iterating over it line by line.
The `re` module has builtin functionality exactly fort his purpose:

```
import re
rx = re.compile('^Container:\s*(.+)', re.M)
with open(your_file) as fp:
    containers = [m.group(1) for m in rx.finditer(fp.read())]
    print(containers)
```